# How to disable C# extension on VS Code changing the color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

After I installed and enabled [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) on VS Code, my text color turned from this:

[image: color_theme-1]

to this:

[image: color_theme-2]

How can I keep the C# extension enabled, but not change the text color?

Thanks!

Comment: No VS-Code user but you can for sure configure the theme somewhere .. probably what happened is that before is was using some other languages syntax theme since it didn't "know" c# before ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the detailed explanation!
I eventually figured out by disabling `Semantic Highlighting`.
What I did:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type in `SemanticHighlighting`
3. Uncheck `Csharp > Semantic Highlighting`

The problem seems like C# extension mistakenly interpret the syntax so it gives the wrong colors.
When I was checking the token with C# extension **DISABLED**, it shows
[image]

but after I **ENABLED** the C# extension, it became

[image]

so I guess that it might mistakenly interprets the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the C# extension adds new [scopes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-tokens-and-scopes), which were not known to VS Code before, and these are now rendered differently (i.e. more exact, better respecting your configured theme). You can check that by running the [scope inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector): press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command while the cursor is on one of the tokens with changing color.

[image]

If you really want to change colours, you can [customize your theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) in VS code by adding something like the following to your [JSON configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "comment.block.js",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000",
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

So what you would have to do:

1. Disable the C# Extension
2. Use the scope inspector to find out all color values that you would like to keep and write them down somewhere
3. Enable the C# Extension again
4. Use the scope inspector to find out all scopes of tokens which changed their color
5. Add a textmate rule for each scope with the previous colour to your settings

Comment: no need to remove the extension, you can disable/enable it

Comment: @rioV8 True, I updated that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Disabling semantic highlighting solved my problem. Posted what I did in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

"First, press Ctrl + , and type "semantic" in the search bar, then set both the "Editor › Semantic Highlighting: Enabled" and "Csharp › Semantic Highlighting: Enabled" options to "false." This fixed the issue for me."